# Какую выбрать конфигурация VPS/VDS для 1500 одновременных посетителей?

Tags: хостинг, vps, vds, xen, openvz

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая проблема: на сайте будет проходить стриминг, соответственно средствами MODX Revolution будет реализован чат. Чат обновляется раз в 1-2 секунды. На стриме ожидается около 1500 человек. Значит, около 1000 запросов в секунду к CMS.
Соответственно вопрос: какую конфигурацию VPS/VDS выбрать для этой цели? Можно на примере тарифов Reg.ru: https://hosting.reg.ru/vps/#xen
OpenVZ или Xen?
Спасибо!

Comment: Оффтоп: а почему бы не реализовать чат менее ресурсозатратными способами? Вебсокеты, pubsub, вот это вот всё

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть на тарифы рег.ру, то понадобится один из последних - Xen-7 либо Xen-8. Но будет ещё сильно зависеть от оптимизации сервера и используемого ПО (какой используется веб-сервер или связка веб-серверов, например). Я однозначно рекомендовал бы смотреть в сторону Xen - на нем в разы меньше вероятность оверселла, т.е. вы получите гарантированные ресурсы.

Я так понял, что нагрузка будет не постоянная, а только во время стрима, так? Если да, то есть гораздо лучше вариант, чем классические VPS – это облачный VPS с почасовой оплатой. Сам пользуюсь VPS у VPS.ua (ссылка на конкретно эту услугу - https://vps.ua/cloud-hosting/). Основной плюс в том, что ресурсы можно добавлять практически на лету и их можно как добавить на определенный период, так и убрать потом.

То есть образно говоря получается так:

- ты пользуешься 6 дней в неделю спокойно своим VPS с 1ГБ ОЗУ и горя не знаешь;
- в день стрима заранее поднимаешь ОЗУ и CPU до нужных лимитов;
- идет стрим, всё продолжает так же летать, как и было до этого;
- по завершению стрима ты снижаешь лимиты до нужных тебе.
  В итоге не переплачиваешь за те ресурсы, которые тебе не нужны бОльшую часть времени, а платишь по факту использования.

Единственный минус - VPS надо выключить для изменения лимитов, но всё это делается в панели парой кликов и реально у меня даунтайм получается около 2 минут, не больше.